# Saiku CE as a plugin for Pentaho 8.3

Tags: pentaho, saiku

I have a question where I am stuck. I have a server where I have raised a Pentaho Community Edition version 8.3. I need to have the Saiku plugin installed to perform a series of analyzes. If I go to the Pentaho Marketplace, it only allows me to install the Saiku as a plugin but to enter the Enterpirse version. I have followed the instructions for generating a license, but this license that I generated has a duration of 30 days.

On the other hand, I have managed to install the Saiku Community Edition service from another account but as a standalone executed with Tomcat. This option is not valid since there is no way to connect it to the Pentaho server.

Any way to install a version of Saiku in Community Edition as a plugin with Pentaho?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you:

https://github.com/dudanogueira/unimed_bi/blob/master/DockerFile

I have just installed pentaho 9, and looks like Saiku is no longer a option to use inside Pentaho as plugin.

Maybe you can still use the last plugin, I have not tried and probably will not use pentaho anymore in favor of Microsoft Power BI.